# cannot map ec2 instance to elastic ip address

Tags: amazon-ec2

trying from web console and as well through command line to associate the elastic ip to a micro instance using command:

```
ec2-associate-address -i <instance id> <elastic ip address>
```

It continuously gives error:

> Client.InvalidParameterCombination: You must specify an allocation id when mapping an address to a VPC instance (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID:

Followed the guide from:https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1346.
Anyone else is facing this issue. Infact I cannot select a running instance from the screen : elastic ip --> associate address and hence web console is out of question...

thanks in advance for any clue...

Comment: These days it is recommended to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to interact with AWS.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what it says on the tin. For an instance in a VPC, you have to provide an allocation ID when you associate an address. See: [Elastic IP Addresses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) for details.

The `ec2-associate-address` style calls are ancient and I believe unmaintained at this point. You should be using the newer [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

Your issue with the console is likely not having any EIPs available for VPC use. You cannot use a non-VPC EIP in a VPC. Allocate a new EIP and make sure you select VPC when doing so.

Answer (score 1):

For VPC, you also need to specify the allocation id of the elastic ip. You are also using old style CLI. To fix your situation, get the `allocation-id` of the elastic ip.

```
ec2-describe-addresses <elastic ip address>
```

This will return a `eipalloc-xxxxxxxx`. Now associate it with the instance.

```
ec2-associate-address -i <instance-id> -a <eipalloc-xxxxxxxx>
```

Now the IP is associated with the instance.